# Get html content of a selector ( .html() ) with jQuery from a JavaScript variable that contains HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript variable that contains a part of html code.
I need to get in this part of html code a div html content.
How can i do it ?
This is an example:

```
var code = '<style type="text/css">
#example{
border:1px;
font-size:20px;
}
</style>
<div id="ex"> Some Content </div>
<div id="ex2"> Some Content <span> Another Content</span></div>
<div id="my_code">This Is My Code.</div><div id="ex3> Etc Etc </div>';
```

I'd like get content of div "my_code" with Jquery .html();

How can i do it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`code` variable it's just a string for your document. If you have parsed this HTML code inside the body then you can use `$('#my_code')`, otherwise it's still just a string so.. that's another story.

Check the other story here: http://jsfiddle.net/NSCQh/1/

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest you have a look at [jQuery's selector overview](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/). They are the most important part of the jQuery magic, and without understanding them you'll get nowhere in the long run.

```
var html = $('#my_code').html()
```

or because that div containts text only

```
var txt = $('#my_code').text()
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got a string, you need a DOM element. From that, you can get the jQuery object.

```
var el = document.createElement('div');
el.innerHTML = code;
console.log($(el));
```

Answer (score 0):

pass the string to jquery and it works

```
var foo = '<div id="foo"> <span class="bar">fooBar</span> </div>';
var inside = $(foo).find('.bar').text();
alert(inside);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an ELEMENT, say `p`.

Use the following

```
$('<p>').append(code).find('div#my_code').html();
```

It create a `p` element, then append the content of variable `code`, then find `div` with `id=my_code` and select it's `innerHTML`.

Working model in the snippet.

```js
var code = `<style type="text/css">
#example{
border:1px;
font-size:20px;
}
</style>
<div id="ex"> Some Content </div>
<div id="ex2"> Some Content <span> Another Content</span></div>
<div id="my_code">This Is My Code.</div><div id="ex3> Etc Etc </div>`;

var elm=$('<p>').append(code).find('div#my_code').html();

console.log(elm);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```