# How can I get content of a contenteditable div with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" href="editor/style.css">           
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>           
    </head>
   <body>
        <div contenteditable="true" class="doc">
            <p contenteditable="true" class="letters" >My editor</p>
        </div>
        <button id="but">Done Editing</button> 

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() 
            {
                $('#but').on('click',function(){
                    //want to obtain all the text within the contenteditable div on clicking the button
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

On clicking the "Done Editing" button I want to get all the text which is entered in my contenteditable div.
Apparently,commands such as

```
var content = $('.doc').text();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get html content of a selector ( .html() ) with jquery from a javascript variable that contains HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21622412/get-html-content-of-a-selector-html-with-jquery-from-a-javascript-variabl)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a **valid selector**. As the div has a class, use the class selector `$('.doc')`

To know more about selectors, refer to [the api docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>My test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="editor/style.css">

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body style="overflow: hidden; margin-top: 50px">
  <div contenteditable="true" class="doc">
    <p contenteditable="true" class="letters">My editor</p>
  </div>
  <button id="but">Done Editing</button>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#but').on('click', function() {
        console.log($('.doc').text());
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your div does not have `id="my-contenteditable-div"`, that is why it does not work.

You can access it this way using jQuery:

---

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#but').on('click', function() {
    console.log($('#myDiv').html());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="myDiv" contenteditable="true">DIV CONTENT</div>
<button id="but">Done Editing</button>
```

*Other alternatives [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16583678/4927984)*

Answer (score 1):

Use the appropriate selector `.letters`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('#but').on('click', function() {
          var content = $('.letters').html();
            console.log(content);
            // do the process here
          });
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>My test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="editor/style.css">

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body style="overflow: hidden; margin-top: 50px">
  <div contenteditable="true" class="doc">
    <p contenteditable="true" class="letters">My editor</p>
  </div>
  <button id="but">Done Editing</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `$('p.letters').html()` or `$('.letters').html()` or both are fine to use? I think that `$('p.letters').html()` is more specific.

Comment: BY using this text if I want to extract the text between anchor tags,<a>anything between these</a>?

Comment: yes @Kaustubh you can the `text` will return the `textContent` whereas the `html` will return the `innerHTML`. FYI, `text()` on an HTML node will give many unwanted space, which you want to trim then.